# Join one table to another based on Mysql Case Statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `PublicForum` that 4 different users can post to, on this table I have 2 fields called `AuthorId(int)` and `AuthorType(Enum)` that shows the User Id and which user wrote the post.

Now I want to select All from `PublicForum` Join 1 of the 4 tables based on the `AuthorType`.

I have tried to do this with Case statement using the code below, but the other 3 tables are returned with NULL values and I want only the table that matches the AuthorType.

```
SELECT PublicForum.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicForumComment WHERE PublicForumComment.ForumId = PublicForum.ForumId) AS CommentCount, 
Student.*, Parent.*, Teacher.*, Counsellor.* FROM PublicForum 
LEFT JOIN Student ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Student' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Student.StudentId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
LEFT JOIN Parent ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Parent' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Parent.ParentId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
LEFT JOIN Teacher ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Teacher' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Teacher.TeacherId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
LEFT JOIN Counsellor ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Counsellor' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Counsellor.CounsellorId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
ORDER BY PublicForum.ForumId DESC LIMIT 10
```

Is there any other way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join conditionally. The way to do this is with separate queries that you combine using `UNION`.

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(pfc.ForumId) AS pfc_count
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, s.StudentName AS Name, s.StudentCol2 AS Col2, s.StudentCol3 AS Col3, s.StudentCol4 AS Col4
    FROM PublicForum AS p
    JOIN Student AS s ON p.AuthorId = s.StudentId
    WHERE p.AuthorType = 'Student'
    UNION
    SELECT p.*, pa.*
    FROM PublicForum AS p
    JOIN Parent AS pa ON p.AuthorId = pa.ParentId
    WHERE p.AuthorType = 'Parent'
    UNION
    SELECT p.*, t.*
    FROM PublicForum AS p
    JOIN Teacher AS t ON p.AuthorId = t.TeacherId
    WHERE p.AuthorType = 'Teacher'
    UNION
    SELECT p.*, c.*
    FROM PublicForum AS p
    JOIN Counsellor AS c ON p.AuthorId = c.CounsellorId
    WHERE p.AuthorType = 'Counsellor') AS t1
LEFT JOIN PublicForumComments AS pfc ON t1.ForumId = pfc.ForumId
GROUP BY t1.ForumId
ORDER BY t1.ForumId DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The use of `tablename.*` for all the joined tables depends on them having the same number of columns, and all the columns are analogous and in the same order. The `AS` clauses in the first subquery then give a generic name to the columns coming from the `UNION`.

Comment: My focus is not really on the `COUNT`. The 4 tables have the same number of columns but different names, what I want is to return all columns from one of the tables and join it with the `PublicForum` table, depending on AuthorType.

Comment: Are the columns in the other table equivalent, so that `Student.col1` is analogous to `Parent.col1`?

Comment: Almost equivalent, same data type but different names. For example: `StudentName` and `TeacherName`

Comment: Why are they separate tables? Why not just a single table, with an additional column `Role` that says whether they're a student, teacher, etc.

Comment: Because there are other Tables that depends on them, Like `Counselllor` table has `AreaOfExpertise` table and teacher has `Klass` table and these tables have to use accurate foreign keys in some other complex tables.

Comment: I've simplified the query to get rid of all the `NULL` placeholders, so the columns from each table will be shown in the same position in the union.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This?  You may have to name the columns and pretty it up..

```
Select * from (
SELECT PublicForum.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicForumComment WHERE PublicForumComment.ForumId = PublicForum.ForumId) AS CommentCount, 
Student.* 
FROM PublicForum 
JOIN Student ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Student' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Student.StudentId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
UNION 
SELECT PublicForum.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicForumComment WHERE PublicForumComment.ForumId = PublicForum.ForumId) AS CommentCount, 
Parent.*
FROM PublicForum 
JOIN Parent ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Parent' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Parent.ParentId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
UNION
SELECT PublicForum.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicForumComment WHERE PublicForumComment.ForumId = PublicForum.ForumId) AS CommentCount, 
Teacher.*
FROM PublicForum 
JOIN Teacher ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Teacher' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Teacher.TeacherId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
UNION
SELECT PublicForum.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PublicForumComment WHERE PublicForumComment.ForumId = PublicForum.ForumId) AS CommentCount, 
Counsellor.*
FROM PublicForum 
JOIN Counsellor ON (CASE WHEN PublicForum.AuthorType='Teacher' AND PublicForum.AuthorId = Teacher.TeacherId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) 
) as tmp1
ORDER BY ForumId DESC LIMIT 10
```